# Servlet with java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed [Apache POI] when export to Excel

Tags: java, excel, servlets, apache-poi

I have the following code and get an exception. Can you help me what I am doing wrong?

```
package com.java400;

import com.ibm.as400.access.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class CallLocalProgramController extends HttpServlet {

    ArrayList<String> listdata;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String message = "";

//        String pno = "816-3999637";
//        String entity = "IB";
        AS400 as400System = new AS400(server, user, pass);
        ProgramCall program = new ProgramCall(as400System);

        try {
            // Initialize the name of the program to run.
            String programName = "/QSYS.LIB/ILMARTINUS.LIB/RRFCFJAVA.PGM";
            // Set up the 3 parameters.
            ProgramParameter[] parameterList = new ProgramParameter[8];

            // Parameter 
            AS400Text textData = new AS400Text(10, as400System);
            parameterList[0] = new ProgramParameter(textData.toBytes("RF320R"));
            textData = new AS400Text(10, as400System);
            parameterList[1] = new ProgramParameter(textData.toBytes("ILMARTINUS"));

            parameterList[2] = new ProgramParameter(30);
            parameterList[3] = new ProgramParameter(30);
            parameterList[4] = new ProgramParameter(30);
            parameterList[5] = new ProgramParameter(30);
            parameterList[6] = new ProgramParameter(30);
            parameterList[7] = new ProgramParameter(50);

            program.setProgram(programName, parameterList);

            // Run the program.
            if (program.run() != true) {
                // Report failure.
                System.out.println("Program failed!");
                // Show the messages.
                AS400Message[] messageList = program.getMessageList();
                for (int i = 0; i < messageList.length; ++i) {
                    // Show each message.
                    System.out.println(messageList[i].getText());
                    // Load additional message information.
                    messageList[i].load();
                    //Show help text.
                    System.out.println(messageList[i].getHelp());
                }
            } // Else no error, get output data.
            else {
                textData = new AS400Text(50, as400System);
                message = (String) textData.toObject(parameterList[7].getOutputData());

                @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
                String[] fields = null;
                String member = "";
                try {
                    if (member.equals("")) {
                        member = "*FIRST";
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error obtaining user input.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                try {
                    as400System.connectService(AS400.RECORDACCESS);
                } catch (AS400SecurityException | IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to connect for record level access.");
                    System.out.println("Check the programmer's guide setup file for special instructions regarding record level access");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                QSYSObjectPathName filePathName = new QSYSObjectPathName("ILMARTINUS", "RFP320R", member, "MBR");  //Note 2 
                SequentialFile theFile = new SequentialFile(as400System, filePathName.getPath());  //Note 3 
                AS400FileRecordDescription recordDescription = new AS400FileRecordDescription(as400System, filePathName.getPath());

                try {
                    RecordFormat[] format = recordDescription.retrieveRecordFormat();
                    //Note 4 
                    fields = format[0].getFieldNames();
                    theFile.setRecordFormat(format[0]);  //Note 5 
                    theFile.open(AS400File.READ_ONLY, 100, AS400File.COMMIT_LOCK_LEVEL_NONE);  //Note 6

                    int count = 0;
                    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
                    int countData = 0;

                    listdata = new ArrayList<>();

                    JSONArray listHeader = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(fields));
                    listdata.add(listHeader.toString());

                    Record record = theFile.readNext();  //Note 7 
                    while (record != null) {
                        JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray();
                        countData = record.getFields().length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < countData; i++) {
                            dataArray.put(record.getField(i).toString());
                        }
                        listdata.add(dataArray.toString());
                        count++;
                        record = theFile.readNext();
                    }
                    //System.out.println();
                    //JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(listdata);
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                    pw.write(listdata.toString());
                    pw.flush();
                    pw.close();

                    theFile.close();  //Note 8 
                    as400System.disconnectService(AS400.RECORDACCESS);  //Note 9

                } catch (AS400Exception | AS400SecurityException | PropertyVetoException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error occurred attempting to display the file.");
                    try {
                        theFile.close();
                    } catch (AS400Exception | AS400SecurityException | IOException | InterruptedException x) {
                    }
                    as400System.disconnectService(AS400.RECORDACCESS);
                }
            }
        } catch (AS400SecurityException | ErrorCompletingRequestException | ObjectDoesNotExistException | PropertyVetoException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Program " + program.getProgram() + " issued an exception!");
        }
        // Done with the server.
        as400System.disconnectAllServices();
        //Print the output from the RPGLE called program 
        System.out.println("Message is: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action.equals("export")) {
            exportToExcel(request, response);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/CallLocalProgram?action=getData").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            doGet(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void exportToExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=RFP320R.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("RFP320R");
        int rowNo = 0;
        int cellnum = 0;

        for (String rowData : listdata) {
            String[] arrRowData = rowData.replace("\"", "")
                    .replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNo++);
            cellnum = 0;
            for (String rData : arrRowData) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                cell.setCellValue(rData);
            }
        }

        wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace

> Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[CallLocalProgramController]:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet CallLocalProgramController threw
>   exception
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:448)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
>         at com.java400.CallLocalProgramController.doPost(CallLocalProgramController.java:178)

Comment: Hi Rully, add some description of your problem, please

Comment: When I run this code, I get an IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after respons has been committed. I apologize, I am new to servlets. What should I do to fix this problem? I want to export data to excel and downloaded